# Submit button from shortcode reloads page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I have a problem that is a bit tricky to describe so please bear with me.

I have a function in a wordpress plugin that populates a particular page.  Within that function is a short-code to access another plugin.  That other plugin produces a calendar on the page with a few buttons.  (With me so far?)

One of those buttons registers the user for a time slot on the calendar.  The problem is that the button is a submit button and ends up triggering the page to reload.  This doesn't happen when I manually enter the shortcode into a regular wordpress page, but when I put it into this function, it seems to cause problems and I'm unable to figure out why exactly.  Below is the function into which I'm trying to insert the shortcode.

```
function page_render($post) {
    global $wpdb;

    require_login();

    $post -> post_content = page_create_nav(6,1)."<span class='subheading'><h2>Thanks!</h2></span>";

    $post->post_content .= <<<EOHTML
    [APCAL]
EOHTML;
    return $post;
}
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you re-write your plugin to post the data via ajax style requests and could therefore could negate the use of traditional form inputs?

Comment: @Scuzzy Thanks for the reply! Maybe I could, though I wouldn't know how exactly.  How do you think this would help?  I'm assuming you're suggesting that I rewrite the plugin I'm working on and not the calendar plugin, right?  (Just to make sure I'm getting what you're saying).  Do you have a particular hypothesis as to why this would be worth looking into?  Thanks again.

Comment: `post_content .= do_shortcode('APCAL');` ?

Comment: @b__ Thanks for the response!  I have indeed given that a shot, but I find that I run into the same problem of it reloading...plus I find that it throws a whole bunch of jquery errors (something I figure I could fix).  But the key issue is that it presents the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that I had a stray `<form method='post'>` tag somewhere in the function.  Got rid of that and it worked like a charm.  :-P